# Using Excel for Mac OSX 16.65 in italian language I'm getting null while trying to combine 2 table columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm using Excel for Mac OSX 16.65 in italian language
I'm trying to combine all unique sorted list of values from 2 columns having date values.

MSFT reference says that you can do:

```
 =SORT(table[colX], table[colY])
```

or

```
 =SORT(table[colX] table[colY])
```

depending on what you want to get.

With excel in Italian language, this translates into:

```
 =ORDINA(table[colX]; table[colY])
```

or

```
 =ORDINA(table[colX] table[colY])
```

I get #VALUE! with the first one, #NULL! with the second one.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which MSFT reference?

Comment: You may be thinking `SORTBY` and not `SORT`  The second criterion of `SORT` is a Long depicting the index to sort on. and in Italian it is `DATI.ORDINA.PER.`

Comment: Here is a link in Italian about it: https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/office/funzione-dati-ordina-per-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f

Comment: Forget about SORT. Even without it, I'm getting those results.

Comment: @BigBen this one https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e